# Obj-C: Check for Empty Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How do you check if an array is empty? (for the record, I looked at similar questions but didn't find the one with this exact problem).

I have a `NSMutableArray` (let's call it `nsma`)that I need to check if empty. If I do `NSLog(@"nsma: %@",nsma);` it logs `nsma: ( )`, but if I do `NSLog(@"nsma count:%@",nsma);` it logs `nsma: (null)`. I need to check if it is empty, but my if statement that does that isn't working for some reason:

```
if (nsma == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"nsma is empty");
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if([nsma count] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"nsma is empty");
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I tried [nsma count] = nil, but of course that didn't work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

check like this

```
    if([array count]==0)
    {
    NSLog(@"Empty");
    }
    else
    {
    NSLog(@"not Empty");
    }
```